# Prove that an irreducible, aperiodic Markov chain has a unique eigenvalue of 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

It is known that for any irreducible, aperiodic Markov chain, there exists one unique eigenvalue of 1. I was told that this statement could be proved by the Perron-Frobenius theorem, but I'm not sure how to get started. I would also be interested in any other ways of proving the statement without using the P-F theorem.

I guess one possible way is to start from the opposite of the situation mentioned in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541742/eigenvalues-of-the-transition-matrix-for-a-periodic-irreducible-markov-chain), but I also need more guidance with it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many versions of Perron-Frobenius theorem. The version for irreducible nonnegative matrices states that, for any irreducible nonnegative matrix, its spectral radius is a simple eigenvalue with a corresponding positive eigenvector.

One easy consequence of the above statement is that, for any irreducible nonnegative matrix, the only eigenvalue that can possibly possess a nonnegative eigenvector is the spectral radius.

In your case, the vector of ones is a nonnegative (actually positive) eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$ of your irreducible Markov chain. Therefore $1$ must be the spectral radius (because the only eigenvalue that can possibly possess a nonnegative eigenvector is the spectral radius). In turn, $1$ is a simple eigenvalue (because the spectral radius is a simple eigenvalue).

Aperiodicity is irrelevant in the argument above.